# JMS queue listeners in a stand alone java program

Tags: java, jms, listener, message-queue

I have a JMS queue configured in a Weblogic server. Messages will be sent to this queue from an external service.

> I want to know :
>    1) If I can consume this message by setting up a
>   message listener in a stand alone java program ?
>   2) Is it mandatory
>   that all JMS queue messages should be consumed by a MDB listener set
>   up in an application server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can consume messages in a stand-alone Java application without the need for any app server or the like.  2) It is not mandatory to use message-driven beans, you can just implement the [MessageListener](https://jms-spec.java.net/2.0/apidocs/javax/jms/MessageListener.html) interface and register it with your [QueueReceiver](https://jms-spec.java.net/2.0/apidocs/javax/jms/QueueReceiver.html); alternatively you can man a blocking call `receive()` directly on the [QueueReceiver](https://jms-spec.java.net/2.0/apidocs/javax/jms/QueueReceiver.html).

Here's a fairly good tutorial with example code that shows how to use JMS in a standalone/non-J2EE app server context: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jms/